# Replacing character with a string in Nginx

Tags: regex, string, nginx

Is there a way I can replace # with '?somecharacter' ?
What i'm trying to do is convert my URL from https://localhost/#afljkdhslfjdsaf to something linke https://localhost/?var=afljkdhslfjdsaf.
While i know how to access query paramerts inside nginx block i've not idea how to capture the # and replace it.

```
location /{
expires -1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass http://ophub-endapp:3000;
}
```

Comment: The *fragment* (the `#` and anything following it) is not sent to the Nginx server, so you cannot process it server-side.

Comment: Yes that's what i read everywhere. No work arounds on nginx itself ???